# Can I generate cryptographically secure random data from a combination of random_device and mt19937 with reseeding?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, cryptography, mersenne-twister

I need to generate cryptographically secure random data in c++11 and I'm worried that using random_device for all the data would severely limit the performance (See slide 23 of Stephan T. Lavavej's "[rand() Considered Harmful](https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http%3A%2F%2Fvideo.ch9.ms%2Fsessions%2Fgonat%2F2013%2FSTLGN13rand.pptx)" where he says that when he tested it (on his system), random_device was 1.93 MB/s and mt19937 was 499 MB/s) as this code will be running on mobile devices (Android via JNI and iOS) which are probably slower than the numbers above.

In addition I'm aware that mt19937 is not cryptographically secure, from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister#Alternatives): "observing a sufficient number of iterations (624 in the case of MT19937, since this is the size of the state vector from which future iterations are produced) allows one to predict all future iterations".

Taking all of the above information into account, can I generate cryptographically secure random data by generating a new random seed from random_device every 624 iterations of mt19937? Or (possibly) better yet, every X iterations where X is a random number (from random_device or mt19937 seeded by random_device) between 1 and 624?

Comment: `random_device` isn't even required to be non-deterministic, so I'd think this isn't a very good idea. If you really need non-deterministic data, using whatever crypto API the OS offers is probably the way to go.

Comment: @Praetorian
On iOS, LLVM uses /dev/urandom as it's source which is guaranteed to be cryptographically secure according to [this](https://www.apple.com/br/ipad/business/docs/iOS_Security_Oct12.pdf) (Page 7).
On Android, gcc uses either /dev/random or /dev/urandom as it's source, I can therefore choose to initialize with "/dev/random" which is used by OpenSSl and others and guarantee (to the best of Android's ability) that it's non-deterministic

Comment: If you know a priori `random_device`'s sources are suitable for use as a CSPRNG, then obviously that's a suitable choice. But I'd still be wary of your `mt19937` idea. A simple rule when it comes to cryptography should be, unless you're an expert in the field, always prefer an existing proven solution over doing something seemingly clever. There's a far greater probability of you screwing something up than of coming up with a truly novel idea. Have you tested the throughput of your idea? `mt19937` has 19937 bits of state, so frequent reseeding might not perform much better than `random_device`

Answer (score 7):

Don't do this. Seriously, just don't. This isn't just asking for trouble--it's more like asking and begging for trouble by going into the most crime-ridden part of the most dangerous city you can find, carrying lots of valuables.

Instead of trying to re-seed MT 19937 often enough to cover up how insecure it is, I'd advise generating your random numbers by running AES in counter mode. This requires that you get one (but only one) good random number of the right size to use as your initial "seed" for your generator.

You use that as the key for AES, and simply use it to encrypt sequential numbers to get a stream of output that looks random, but is easy to reproduce.

This has many advantages. First, it uses an algorithm that's actually been studied heavily, and is generally believed to be quite secure. Second, it means you only need to distribute *one* (fairly small) random number as the "key" for the system as a whole. Third, it probably gives *better* throughput. Both [Intel's](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-aes-ni-performance-enhancements-hytrust-datacontrol-case-study) and (seemingly) [independent tests](https://calomel.org/aesni_ssl_performance.html) show a range of throughput that starts out competitive with what you're quoting for MT 19937 at the low end, and up to around 4-5 times faster at the top end. Given the way you're using it, I'd expect to see you get results close to (and possibly even exceeding<sup>1</sup>) the top end of the range they show.

Bottom line: AES in counter mode is obviously a better solution to the problem at hand. The very best you can hope for is that MT 19937 ends up close to as fast and close to as secure. In reality, it'll probably disappoint both those hopes, and end up both slower and substantially less secure.

---

<sub>1. How would it exceed those results? Those are undoubtedly based on encrypting bulk data--i.e., reading a block of data from RAM, encrypting it, and writing the result back to RAM. In your case, you don't need to read the result from RAM--you just have to generate consecutive numbers in the CPU, encrypt them, and write out the results.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is, no you cannot.  The requirements for a cryptographically secure RNG are very stringent, and if you have to ask this question here, then you are not sufficiently aware of those requirements.  As Jerry says, AES-CTR is one option, if you need repeatability.  Another option, which does not allow repeatability, would be to look for an implementation of Yarrow or [Fortuna](https://www.schneier.com/fortuna.html) for your system.  In general it is much better to find a CSRNG in a library than to roll your own.  Library writers *are* sufficiently aware of the requirements for a good CSRNG.